# PySpark GroupBy - Keep Value or Null if No Value

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm coding in PySpark and have a data frame that has tokens and their associated phrases. The same phrase can appear in multiple rows so I want to groupby so that there is only one row of the phrase, but I want to keep the one that has an associated descriptor. If there is no descriptor, I want to keep one row with the null.
Example data set:

```
+------------------------------------+--------+-------+---------+------------+-----------+
|            SENTENCE                | SENT_ID|  TOKEN| TOKEN_ID|     PHRASE | DESCRIPTOR|
+------------------------------------+--------+-------+---------+------------+-----------+
|The handle of the old razor blade...|       1| handle|        2|      handle|       null|
|The handle of the old razor blade...|       1|  razor|        6| razor blade|       null|
|The handle of the old razor blade...|       1|  blade|        7| razor blade|        old|
```

I want it to look like:

```
+------------------------------------+--------+------------+-----------+
|            SENTENCE                | SENT_ID|     PHRASE | DESCRIPTOR|
+------------------------------------+--------+------------+-----------+
|The handle of the old razor blade...|       1|      handle|       null|
|The handle of the old razor blade...|       1| razor blade|        old|
```

There will never be a situation where there are different descriptors for the same phrase. I'm thinking something like
`df.groupby('REVIEW_ID','SENT_ID','PHRASE')` but not sure how to bring in the descriptor.

Comment: Show what you have tried. What are you expecting to happen if there are 2 non-null values?

Comment: Not sure what to try. There is never a situation where there are 2 non-nulls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `collect_list` or `collect_set` functions to get **`descriptor`** values.

- `collect_list`,`collect_set` doesn't preserve **null** values for this case use when otherwise to replace with string `null`.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---+----+------+
#| id|name|salary|
#+---+----+------+
#|  1|   a|   100|
#|  1|null|   200|
#|  1|null|   300|
#+---+----+------+

#grouping by id and collecting names

df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(col("name")).alias("list")).show()
#+---+----+
#| id|list|
#+---+----+
#|  1| [a]|
#+---+----+

#preserve nulls without duplicates
df.groupBy("id").\
agg(concat_ws(",",collect_list(when(isnull(col("name")),lit('null')).otherwise(col("name")))).alias("list")).\
show()
#+---+-----------+
#| id|       list|
#+---+-----------+
#|  1|a,null,null|
#+---+-----------+

#preserve nulls without duplicates
df.groupBy("id").\
agg(concat_ws(",",collect_set(when(isnull(col("name")),lit('null')).otherwise(col("name")))).alias("list")).\
show()
+---+------+
| id|  list|
+---+------+
|  1|a,null|
+---+------+
```

Comment: So in this situation I would want the first one where id 1 only returns a for list. But if there were an id 2 and it only had null values, then I would want to return just 1 null value

Comment: use `collect_set` after groupBy instead of `collect_list`. Check my answer I added full syntax in `#preserve nulls without duplicates` section.

Comment: But in your example I would not want the null to be preserved for id 1 because it has a. I would only want the null if there were no other non-null values there

Comment: Used your first example, looks to work for nulls by just having an empty list. Thanks